# Storing binary data as a string in a Web Sql Database

Tags: javascript, performance, sqlite, local-storage

Ok, so I am downloading chunks of data via xhr and I want to store it locally for a chrome extension.

At first I was able to store it in `localStorage`, but then I needed to move on to larger chunks that localStorage can't handle.So I decided to store it in a [Web Sql Database](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/). However I was able to store the data in `localStorage` exactly as it was downloaded but when I try to store it in the database the data gets lost or I get an error.

Like so:

```
//this way the data gets lost because it is filtered to prevent SQL injection attacks
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO files (id, content) VALUES (?,?)', [fileID,file]);

//this method gives an error (unrecognized token) because the data contains byte values in the string  
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO files (id, content) VALUES (?, "' + file + '")', [id]);
```

The only other way I can think of getting the data into the database is by using `btoa(file)`, and it works but I'm thinking that the performance will take a fairly substantial hit if it has to do an `btoa` / `atob` every time the data is stored / used.

So my question is then, how do you store the data in the database without using `btoa`, or if that's not possible how much performance does `btoa` use?

I'm also fairly certain that `localStorage` uses SQLite as well as a Web Sql Database, so why can't I just put the data in the latter as easily as I can with `localStorage`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at something like this, you'd need to base64 encode the binary data, as it will need to be printable characters.

http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html

It will result in about a four-fold increase in the size of the binary data though.

You'd need to encode it as hexadecimal I believe, maybe, to represent binary data using SQLite

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO files (id, content) VALUES (2, "0xBADF00D12840F32");');
```

For example, the latter SQLite method would probably be more efficient.